# How to fix RED kibana status

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, kibana

Here is the cluster status

```
Status Breakdown
ID  Status
ui settings     Elasticsearch plugin is red
plugin:kibana@5.2.2     Ready
plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.2  This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v5.2.2 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v5.1.1 @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)
plugin:console@5.2.2    Ready
plugin:timelion@5.2.2   Ready *emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that one of your node contains elasticsearch version 5.1.1 and elasticsearch may be works fine,if all nodes contains same version.

so you need to upgrade your elasticsearch with respect to your kibana version

you can check it with the official reference

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/fixed-elasticsearch-plugin-is-red-after-6-0-0-upgrade/109604/5

Answer (score 0):

Install or update elasticsearch.

RedHat/Centos :
try `yum update` then `yum upgrade`

Debian/Ubuntu :
try `apt-get remove elasticsearch` and `apt-get install elasticsearch`

Reference :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/install.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html

Answer (score 0):

In ELK (Elasticsearch , Logstash, Kibana) ES & Kibana follow symmetry pattern where in version of elasticsearch and kibana should be same .
In your case Elastic Version seems to be  5.1.1  and kibana is 5.2.2